# Store enum value in Object Box with generic mapper

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums, objectbox

I joined project recently that uses Object Box.

I read documentation and it looks like I have to write converter all the time when I try to store enum value in the Object Box (https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types#convert-annotation-and-property-converter).

Unfortunately, it looks really tedious to write all the time similar code for different enums. Is there easy way to write some generic mapper? Even it will violate the requirement not to use enum case name?

Answer (score 0):

A generic mapper should be easy to write - for one direction at least; e.g. have a interface `StableValue` like this:

```
interface StableValue {
    int getStableValue();
}
```

Then you should be able to write a generic converter.

Actually, I'll take that to the team to talk about integrating this into ObjectBox....

Comment: So solution will be to have interface that all enum classes should inherit from.  I see clear the storing part but I don't see the converted from database int value to the specific enum class value.

Comment: Yes, that'd solve half of it. If you have many converters it might be a starting point. You could also have all converters in one file, btw.

Comment: I prefer not to have all converters in one file especially for the multi module project